# iOS Push Notifications not working through GCM using Phonegap-plugin-push

Tags: ios, mobile, ionic-framework, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

When using phonegap-plugin-push, we are creating a mobile application that uses GCM to send out push notifications to the mobile devices. We are able to push to Android devices correctly using GCM. The plugin gives us both the GCM and APNS registration tokens. When we use the GCM token to push to the APNS we are unable to push to the iOS device, however when we test the APNS token directly, we are able to push the notification. When using the GCM token and a test service we receive a "success" message, but no notification makes it to the device. We know that the device token is correct as we can send a notification directly using an online APNS push service. We have created all the certificates, we have development and production certificates.

As we receive a registration token from the GCM service using the device token and APNS token, I believe the problem lies within the communication between GCM and the device itself. As we are not receiving the notification to the device using GCM, but we are able to use the APNS token generated on registration to directly push to the device. The GCM with the registration token, will not push to device.

This link here describes the problem https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/532

Answer (score 1):

There might be some problem with your provisional profile.
This tutorial might help you.
https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjr__OblLTNAhWHkpQKHT6MBUgQFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.raywenderlich.com%2F123862%2Fpush-notifications-tutorial&usg=AFQjCNFaM0baTw-x3Swz12MwCPu5XqEtLA&sig2=6wIOeDF8AvtCQfrheM2FXw

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply, I believe this is for native APNS, where we are trying to use GCM to send our iOS push notifications, i tried to clarify the question